# Routing submenu elements Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have a question regarding routing submenu elements in Angular 2.

The directory of my project looks like:

```
-app  
---login  
---registration  
---mainApp  (this is the main body of the app, with a static content as menu, with few links)
-----subMenu1  (link to some content)
-------(some files here)  
-----subMenu2   (link to some content)
-------(some files here)  
-----subMenu3   (link to some content)
-------(some files here)  
---app.component.ts  
---app.component.html  
---app.module.ts  
---app.routing  
---index.ts
```

How does it works? First view is the `login` and there you have two possibilities, to enter the `mainApp` or enter `registration` form. It works fine. But now I need to handle the routing between the `mainApp` and sub items from this mainApp. The `mainApp` content is just a sidemenu, which doesn't disappear. It is always on screen, only content from sidemenu elements is changing.

**What is my problem:**

Do I need to provide another routing file to handle the routing between the `mainApp` static menu elements and the dynamic content? Or am I able to do it just from this file which handles routing between the `app` and `login`, `registration` and `mainApp`?

**And if I have to make another routing file, how would it look like?**

My actual routing file looks like:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainAppComponent} from './mainApp/index';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'mainApp', component: MainAppComponent },
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**Let's say that I provide another routing file, would it look like this?**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { subMenu1Component } from './subMenu1/index';
import { subMenu2Component } from './subMenu2/index';
import { subMenu3Component } from './subMenu3/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: mainAppComponent},
  { path: 'subMenu1', component: subMenu1Component },
  { path: 'subMenu2', component: subMenu2Component },
  { path: 'subMenu3', component: subMenu3Component },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to split my routes off into layouts. So typically I do a secure layout and a public layout. This way I can control the authentication of the website and protect data that was meant to be secure.

In order to do this I keep a file structure as shown below,

```
/app.module.ts
/app.routing.ts

/layouts/secure.component.ts
/layouts/secure.component.html
/layouts/public.component.ts
/layouts/public.component.html

/secure/profile.component.ts
/secure/profile.component.html
/secure/secure.routes.ts

/public/home.component.ts
/public/home.component.html
/public/public.routes.ts
```

**Explanation**

Initially we need to register all of our components and setup the routes.

**Register Components**

**/app.module.ts**

```
//Layouts
import { PublicComponent }                  from './layouts/public.component';
import { SecureComponent }                  from './layouts/secure.component';
import { HomeComponent }                    from './public/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent }                 from './secure/profile.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PublicComponent,
        SecureComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ProfileComponent
], 
providers: [ 
    Guard,
    Auth
    ]
```

Take special notice to the Auth under providers. This is what will help us secure the secure layout.

Next we will setup the routes.

**app.routing.ts**

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full', },
    { path: '', component: PublicComponent, data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
];
```

As you can see the [Guard] is setup using the Auth provider and is a service I use to secure the secure layouts. Now that each of these routes actually have children routes we can set those routes up to control the actual navigation of our app.

It is important to understand. These routes will direct traffic to the correct layout. Then depending on the route the child routes take over. Which in your case would be your sub components.

**/secure/secure.routes.ts**

```
import { ProfileComponent }                   from './profile.component';

export const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
];
```

Remember to import your component to the routes file so it knows which class to call when the route is enabled.

For extra credit I will go ahead and throw in a service to provide auth. This will show you how to protect your routes.

**guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }                      from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Auth }                 from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class Guard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(protected router: Router, protected auth: Auth ) {}

     canActivate() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

By storing a token in the `local storage` we can check to see if it exist and authenticate the user. Once they meet the criteria they gain access to the secure routes.

Let me know if you have anymore questions.